# how do user threads and kernel threads work with the linux stack?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, stack, kernel

When a user thread is used, is there one stack for every thread or just one thread for the whole process? And how does it work with kernel threads?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Every thread has its own stack, both regular threads and kernel-only threads.